# How do I repeat this function to call the API depending on the value that is returned to me?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am having an issue which I want to repeat the action of fetching data and making a post request to an API repeated times until the data I receive is the specific I want. How can I do that and what am I doing wrong with my code? Here is it so far:

```js
function diceBet(){
   
    do {
    fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "x-access-token": api,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(
            bodyReq
        )}).then(function(resp){
            return resp.json()
        }).then(function(respData){
                console.log(respData);
            })
            
    }while(respData.data.diceRoll.result <= 99)}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood well, but you could use a boolean flag with an if. If it should repeat, just turn this boolean flag into true (and let the `while` repeat)

Comment: @AlexanderSantos I don't think that will help OP here. The issue is that his loop is outside the promise, so respData is never a resolved promise in the conditional. The other answers using async await of course await the promise resolution before continuing, so the conditional works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `async` function and `await`.

```js
async function diceBet() {
    let respData;
    do {
        respData = await (await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "x-access-token": api,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(
                bodyReq
            )
        })).json();
    } while (respData.data.diceRoll.result <= 99)
}
```

Comment: thanks !! it worked :)

Comment: @Narchy Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a `if` loop, but like mentioned above, with `async` & `await`. I personally like the `if` loop more, but it does not really matter I suppose.

```
async function diceBet() { 
   await ( .. // fetching here )
 }

if(result < 99) diceBet() // call your function again until condition is met
```